# How to simulate pressing Enter in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, rspec-rails

I have a test with RSpec like below

```
describe "visitor do search" do      
  before do
      fill_in "keyword", with: "London"
      click_button "search_all"
    end

    it "should visit search result path" do
      page.should have_selector('title', :text => "Search Result")
    end
end
```

I want to remove the button 'search_all' and change it with event like pressing enter by keyboard.

How do I write code for that with RSpec ?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), which is a Capybara driver allowing you to test Javascript. Simply read the doc to install it and make it work in your project, then you should be able to simulate a click on the keyboard using this piece of code:

```
keypress = "var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 }); $('body').trigger(e);"
page.driver.execute_script(keypress)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

Just add a '\n' to the end of your query string:

```
fill_in "keyword", with: "London\n"
```

Comment: Very nice. I almost installed Qt with capybara-webkit for this super trivial task. I am using rspec with capybara and this also worked: `find('#thing').set "word\n"`

Comment: Note that this only works if you use double quotes for the `with` value. If you use single quotes, like `with: 'London\n'`, it will actually type out the newline, since escape sequences don't work inside single quotes except for escaping single quote characters.