# Capybara: NotSupportedByDriverError when trying to simulate pressing <ENTER>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am writing a spec using Capybara to test the functionality of a search bar on my website. After following the instructions on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542185/how-to-simulate-pressing-enter-in-rspec) on how to simulate pressing the Enter Key in Rspec/Capybara, I get the following error when I run my tests:

```
 Failure/Error: page.driver.execute_script(keypress)
 Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
   Capybara::Driver::Base#execute_script
```

Am I doing something wrong? Here are the contents of my spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Search' do
  it 'displays no results when non-existent things are looked up'   do

  visit root_path

  page.first(".search-icon-small").click

  fill_in "search", with: "NonExistent"

  #simulate pressing Enter
  keypress ="var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 }); $('body').trigger(e);"
  page.driver.execute_script(keypress)

  page.should have_content('No Results')
  end

  it 'displays content that exists' do
    #Clients
    client = Client.new
    client.name = 'Gerard Leskovar'
    client.save!

    visit root_path


    page.first(".search-icon-small").click

    fill_in "search", with: "Leskovar"

    keypress ="var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 }); $('body').trigger(e);"
    page.driver.execute_script(keypress)

    page.should have_content('Gerard Leskovar')

  end
end
```

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I didn't have the capybara-webkit gem installed!

Comment: If anyone has an answer for this when using Poltergeis as Capybara driver, I'll appreciate it :)

Comment: I have the gem in my gemfile and I did `bundle` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Ohhh I just forgot `, js: true`

Comment: I have js: true and capybara-webkit installed, still seeing this on all my attempts to call evaluate_script. Any other leads on this? All my google searches are leading me to dead-ends, like this SO page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so I didn't have the `capybara-webkit` installed and therefore I got the error that I did. Thank you!

Comment: Development has been suspended for capybara-webkit. You should use the Selenium or Apparition drivers.