# cucumber click dialog remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, cucumberjs

Checking if attribute was excluded, confirm dialog, using rails 4

```
    Quando(/^confirmo$/) do
       page.execute_script 'window.confirm = function () { return true }'
    end
```

return error

```
>  Capybara::Driver::Base#execute_script (Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError)
      ./features/step_definitions/covenats_steps.rb:80:in `/^confirmo$/'
      features/covenats.feature:48:in `E confirmo'
```

gems install

```
group :test do
   gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4'
   gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3'
   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why you get this error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capybara: NotSupportedByDriverError when trying to simulate pressing <ENTER>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069240/capybara-notsupportedbydrivererror-when-trying-to-simulate-pressing-enter)