# Feature specs for read-only date picker input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am writing feature specs for a form written in haml. The form takes input of a date using date picker. It has been made read-only.

I am trying to fill in the date using the following

> page.execute_script("$('#start-date').val('11/10/2016')")

where "start-date" is the id of the input field.

As this requires javascript, I have used the selenium-webdriver gem of version 3.0.1.

My firefox version is 47.0.

When I run the specs, I am getting the following error:

> Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
>          Capybara::Driver::Base#execute_script

In spec_helper.rb, I have included the following

> require 'capybara/rspec'

What is the reason behind this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does your `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb` look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capybara: NotSupportedByDriverError when trying to simulate pressing <ENTER>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069240/capybara-notsupportedbydrivererror-when-trying-to-simulate-pressing-enter)